# Error when committing

Tags: flask, psycopg2

I am setting up a simple application using flask and psycopg2. When I try to do a simple database update, I get an "Internal server error", throwing in some logging, it is clear that

```
@app.route('/deactivate/<pid>')
def deactivate(pid):
 try:
    sql='update person set active = \'false\' where id = %s'
    logger.debug(LOGID+' running '+sql)
    cur.execute(sql,[pid])
    logger.debug(LOGID+' ran '+sql)
    cur.commit()
    logger.debug(LOGID+' commited '+sql)
```

Throwing in some logging, it is clear that it fail in "commit" - I am not able to find any explanation in any logs, neither from postgres nor apache. The updated value will show up in any call within the same application, so the update obiously went well, but if I try to query from anything else, the update if (of cource) not there. Any clue on what goes wrong?

Comment: Where does `cur` come from? Are you sure you're querying the same database the app is using?

Comment: Absolutely. I can update the db in other places and see the updates, I just cannot manage to commit a change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commit` is a method of psycopg2's [`connection` class](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit), not the [`cursor` class](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html). Since you don't show us the `except` clause, I assume that it's swallowing the `AttributeError` raised when you call `cur.commit()`.

Without knowing where `cur` comes from, I don't know if your connection object is available in the module, but it needs to be. You'll then want to modify your code to look something like this:

```
@app.route('/deactivate/<pid>')
def deactivate(pid):
    try:
        sql = "update person set active = 'false' where id = %s"
        cur.execute(sql, [pid])
        conn.commit()
    except SomeSpecificException:
        # exception handling code here
```